# How to use valid? method on an array in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on an app in rails 3.

I have several records that i want to save to my database. I am trying to make sure that all the objects in an array (the records are stored in an array) are valid before saving. The Owner model validates the presence of name and email. In the rails console, I have tried the following:

```
@owner = Array.new
=> []

@owner[0] = Owner.new (name:"peter", email:"peter@gmail.com")
=> returns object

@owner[1] = Owner.new (name:"fred", email:"fred@gmail.com")
=> returns object

@owner[2] = Owner.new (name:"", email:"")
=> returns object

@owner[0].valid?
=> true

@owner[1].valid?
=> true

@owner[2].valid?
=> false

@owner.each { |t| t.valid? }
=> returns an array like this: [object1, object2, object3]. I would expect something like this instead: [true,true,false]
```

I dont understand why the .valid? method works fine if I individually check the elements of the array using @owner[i], but doesnt work correctly if I'm using .each to iterate through the array. Anybody know what might be the problem?

What I am trying to do is achieve something like this:

```
(@owner.each { |t| t.valid? }).all?
```

To make sure that each record is valid, then I can proceed to save them.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Each does not return an array of `valid?` values. You probably want either:

```
(@owner.collect { |t| t.valid? }).all?
```

or

```
(@owner.all? { |t| t.valid? })
```

The examples can also be written as:

```
@owner.collect(&:valid?).all?
```

or

```
@owner.all?(&:valid?)
```

Comment: Thank you, both options worked perfectly. I have to read up on the differences between each and collect.

Comment: There's not much to read up about... `each` just runs the block for each element of the Array, `map` or `collect` runs the block for each element of the Array **AND** collects the return value for each iteration of the block into a new Array.